# LDAP error code 49 AcceptSecurityContext error data 52e v2580 even with the correct credentials

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, ldap

I'm adding LDAP authentication to the spring-boot application. All set accordingly and I'm getting "LDAP error code 49 AcceptSecurityContext error data 52e v2580" error even after providing correct credentials.

I'm using `import javax.naming.Context;` and have mentioned the code below.

```java
String url = ldap_url;
String domain = ldap_domain;
String uname = request.getUsername();
String pwd = request.getPassword();
boolean authentication = false;
boolean error = true;
String msg;
String ldapSearchBase = "OU=TEST_OU, DC=DC2, DC=DC1";

// create env for initial context
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "CN=" + uname + "@" + domain + "," + ldapSearchBase);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pwd);
NamingEnumeration results = null;

try {
    LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
    authentication = true;
    error = false;
} catch (NamingException e) {
    logger.error("LDAP error for :{NamingException}" + e);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new ApiResponse(true, e.getMessage()));
} finally {
    if (!error) {
        msg = "Login success!!!";
    } else {
        msg = "Authentication failed!";
    }
}

logger.info("exitinig...");

if (authentication) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new ApiResponse(false, msg));
} else {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new ApiResponse(true, msg));
}
```

Error is catching as `NamingException`.

Answer (score 5):

An error response with LDAP error [code 49 ... data 52e](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=Common%20Active%20Directory%20Bind%20Errors) "Returns when username is valid **but password/credential is invalid**."

There could be infrastructure issues such as [when the domain controller computer account may not be synchronized with the Key Distribution Center (KDC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/cc526636(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). However you would probably have a lot more other issues when this condition exists.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't understand the error mentioning this as a credential issue. I have doubt on the SECURITY_PRINCIPAL.

Comment: You may want to get a known good LDAP Browser (or use a ldapsearch utility) to verify your parameters. (I like Apache Studio). The LDAP result code You might try using the userPrincipal name for login (username@example.com) instead of the DN. Sometimes improper escaping of the DN is a culprit but I would assume you would get a different result code if the username was wrong.

Comment: (username@example.com) instead of the DN was my case - thanks !

Answer (score 1):

`LDAP error code 49 AcceptSecurityContext` - I hit this error with correct credentials

- It appears if the account is **locked** in **Windows Active Directory** (& I expect also under LDAP in Linux)
- Unlocking the account fixes this error

Answer (score 0):

You might get this error in Active directory (Windows popular implementation of LDAP) if you specify the username but not the windows domain.

This is what you should do:

USERNAME: <YOUR_WINDOWS_DOMAIN>\<YOUR_USERNAME>

PASSWORD: <YOUR_PASSWORD>

Answer (score -1):

This can occur when your account requires a SmartCard to sign in.

There is a setting in Active Directory called "Smart card is required for interactive logon".

[image]